# Is there an R function to get values between 2 numbers based on a specific step size?

Tags: r

I want to find values, say, 200 and 5000 with 18 steps. So far, I have tried this:

```
lower_lim = 200
upper_lim = 5000
step_num = 18
step_size = (upper_lim - lower_lim) / step_num
seq(from = lower_lim, to = upper_lim, by = step_size)
```

This seems to work fine, but gives me 19 values instead of 18. Also, this approach seems not efficient. Is there a function that requires `lower_lim`, `upper_lim` and `step_num` and gives back the values (`number of values = step_num`) between `lower_lim` and `upper_lim`?

Comment: `seq(lower_lim, upper_lim, length.out = step_num)`

Comment: It seems your requirements might be in conflict from an off-by-one / "fencepost" error: do you want to specify the number of steps, or do you want to specify the step size that would exist if you didn't need both the beginning and end points included?

Comment: @JonSpring it is not too important whether the beginning and end points are included or not as long as the 18 values are within the range `lower_lim` and `upper_lim`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  can do

```
step_size <- (upper_lim - lower_lim) / (step_num - 1)
seq(from = lower_lim, to = upper_lim, by = step_size)
```

or

```
seq(lower_lim, upper_lim, length.out = step_num)
```

Answer (score 1):

`tidyr` also has a similar `full_seq` function for this:

```
tidyr::full_seq(c(lower_lim, upper_lim), step_size)
```